# Is imaging independent of partition size?

Tags: clone, clonezilla, imaging

Let's assume this scenario. A partition of 100GB, 50GB are used and 50GB are free. If I do the image of the system, could I then resize the partition to 75GB and be able to restore the image? Or is it like cloning where the partition needs to have the same size?

Comment: Given you tag, are you only talking about clonezilla?  Or are you asking about any imaging tool.

Comment: @Zoredache Rather than tool-specific, the question is about imaging in general. I put the CloneZilla tag because it's the tool I have used for cloning partitions.

Comment: The answer then is, depends on tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitions don't really have free/used space, filesystems do.  If your imaging tool recognizes and has support for a given filesystem, then it can resize.

I am pretty sure clonezilla has at least ext*, fat, and ntfs resize support.

See the expert resize option.

http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone/advanced/05-advanced-param.php